# Select distinct number from a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have got a list of numbers (say x-y coordinates)

```
a={{-99.107159975257815156, 0}, {-99.107159975199010630, 
  0}, {-99.107142118737087314, 0}, {-99.107142118737058893, 
  0}, {-99.107142118737058893, 0}, {-98.809552110008141289, 
  0}, {-95.833332619319349971, 0}, {-95.535743059443774445, 
  0}, {-95.238127643771221612, 0}, {-94.345237392311275941, 
  0}, {-93.067528042225021040, 0}, {-91.964285029098363129, 
  0}, {-91.666688282908694448, 0}, {-90.931371871528057200, 
  0}, {-90.608464933379565328, 0}, {-90.476189802090317444, 
  0}, {-90.476189802090317444, 0}, {-90.178570756688671413, 
  0}, {-89.583351887655183554, 0}, {-89.583332665885464525, 0}}
```

As we can see from the pattern that the points are very very close.

If I want to remove those points which are very close say by comparing the x and y coordinates of the consecutive coordinates, how will code. I have seen some functions like `Select`, `Cases`, `DeleteDuplicates`and `Sort` will be useful, but the example are for single array of numbers.

For example

```
    b={-99.107159975257815156, -99.107159975199010630, \
    -99.107142118737087314, -98.809552110008141289, 95.833332619319349971};
Sort@DeleteDuplicates[b, Abs[#2 - #1] < 10^-2 &]
```

How can I proceed like this for list containing two arrays (Eg. list `a` given above)

Comment: `Sort@DeleteDuplicates[a, Norm[#1 - #2, 2] < 10^-2 &]`? You can play around with the second argument to norm, for `2` it is the usual Euclidean norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the list of points is very long, `Nearest` can help to find clusters more efficiently:

```
ϵ = 0.01
clusters = DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Nearest[a -> Automatic, a, {∞, ϵ}]];
```

Here, `ϵ = 0.01` is the clustering radius; it is a parameter that you may adjust to your needs.

Afterwards you may create a new list containing only the first representatives of each cluster:

```
b = a[[clusters[[All, 1]]]]
```

> {{-99.10715997525781516, 0}, {-98.80955211000814129,    0},
>   {-95.83333261931934997, 0}, {-95.53574305944377445,    0},
>   {-95.23812764377122161, 0}, {-94.34523739231127594,    0},
>   {-93.06752804222502104, 0}, {-91.96428502909836313,    0},
>   {-91.66668828290869445, 0}, {-90.931371871528057200,    0},
>   {-90.608464933379565328, 0}, {-90.47618980209031744,    0},
>   {-90.178570756688671413, 0}, {-89.58335188765518355, 0}}

Or you can create a new list containing the means of the clusters:

```
c = Compile[{{pts, _Real, 2}, {idx, _Integer, 1}},
   Mean[pts[[idx]]],
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True
   ][a, clusters]
```

> {{-99.1071, 0.}, {-98.8096, 0.}, {-95.8333, 0.}, {-95.5357, 
>     0.}, {-95.2381, 0.}, {-94.3452, 0.}, {-93.0675, 0.}, {-91.9643, 
>     0.}, {-91.6667, 0.}, {-90.9314, 0.}, {-90.6085, 0.}, {-90.4762, 
>     0.}, {-90.1786, 0.}, {-89.5833, 0.}}